# Get return value of a function using notifySubscribers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I got two different view models and I need to call a function in one view model from other. To acheive this i try to use `ko.subscribable()`

```
 var postbox=new ko.subscribable();// global variable
```

EmployeeViewModel

```
  postbox.subscribe(function (showAlert) {
            return that.ValidateEmployees(showAlert);
        }, that, 'ValidateEmps');

  that.ValidateEmployees=function(){

  //validation logic
   return true/false;
  }
```

TaxCalculatorViewModel

```
var isEmpValid = postbox.notifySubscribers(true, "ValidateEmps");
 if (!isEmpValid ) {
  return false;
 }
```

The prioblem is I am always getting `isEmpValid=undefined` instead of getting the return value of `ValidateEmployees`

**How to get the return value of a function when we pass using notifySubscribers?**

Comment: @Quentin, is it applicable to `ko` knockout? So calling like `postbox.notifySubscribers(true, "ValidateEmps")()` will resolve?

Comment: KO subscriptions are "one way". So the `notifySubscribers` just sends out the message and in the subscribe you read that message and that is it there is no way to return from an event handler. If you need "two way" commutation then you need to need events: http://jsfiddle.net/h0j773xg/

Comment: @nemesv, Thank you veru much!. Is there any example to acheive this with events? I am trying to call another viewmodel method and expecting the return results.