# How to update view model data from another view model in Knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I am using Knock out to bind different sections in a page. I have two view model data for each section. While changing a element in one view model based on that want to change another element in another view Model.Each view model data have ID field to identify each data.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892124/whats-the-best-way-of-linking-synchronising-view-models-in-knockout

Comment: @gkb How to find by ID and update ? Same ID is used in both View Model

Comment: I would suggest to provide some code that presents some specific task that you want to achieve..

Comment: @gkb I have an ID field in both models which are same.When change a text field in on model I want to change the same ID text in another model.

Comment: @gkb 'postbox.subscribe(function (newValue) {       
        self.text(newValue);
    }, this, "selected");

postbox.notifySubscribersself.text(), "selected");'

Comment: I have created this fiddle based on your comment above - https://jsfiddle.net/usxvqq9c/1/ ..have a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass one of the view model in to the other view model:

```
var ViewModel1 = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
};

var ViewModel2 = function(viewModel) {
    self = this;
    self.content = ko.observable();
    viewModel.selectedItem.subscribe(function(){
       self.content('value changed')
    });
};


var viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
var viewModel2 = new ViewModel2(viewModel1);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel1, document.getElementById("part1"));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel2, document.getElementById("part2"));
```