# KnockoutJS - update observable from another modelview

Tags: knockout.js, observable, model-view

I have an existing `ComposePopupView()` modelview which contains observable

```
this.attachments = ko.observableArray([]);
```

and a method below

```
ComposePopupView.prototype.addDropboxAttachment = function (oDropboxFile)
{
    var
        oAttachment = null,
        iAttachmentSizeLimit = Utils.pInt(Settings.settingsGet('AttachmentLimit')),
        mSize = oDropboxFile['bytes']
    ;

    oAttachment = new ComposeAttachmentModel(
        oDropboxFile['link'], oDropboxFile['name'], mSize
    );

    oAttachment.fromMessage = false;
    oAttachment.cancel = this.cancelAttachmentHelper(oDropboxFile['link']);
    oAttachment.waiting(false).uploading(true).complete(false);

    this.attachments.push(oAttachment);

    this.attachmentsPlace(true);

    if (0 < mSize && 0 < iAttachmentSizeLimit && iAttachmentSizeLimit < mSize)
    {
        oAttachment.uploading(false).complete(true);
        oAttachment.error(Translator.i18n('UPLOAD/ERROR_FILE_IS_TOO_BIG'));
        return false;
    }

    Remote.composeUploadExternals(function (sResult, oData) {

        var bResult = false;
        oAttachment.uploading(false).complete(true);

        if (Enums.StorageResultType.Success === sResult && oData && oData.Result)
        {
            if (oData.Result[oAttachment.id])
            {
                bResult = true;
                oAttachment.tempName(oData.Result[oAttachment.id]);
            }
        }

        if (!bResult)
        {
            oAttachment.error(Translator.getUploadErrorDescByCode(Enums.UploadErrorCode.FileNoUploaded));
        }

    }, [oDropboxFile['link']]);

    return true;
};
```

Then I have created my other modelview called `UsersDocumentsPopupView()` where I'm accessing above method as

```
DropBox = __webpack_require__(/*! View/Popup/Compose */ 31)
....
DropBox.prototype.addDropboxAttachment(aFiles[0]);
```

but it throws an error

> Cannot read property 'attachments' of undefined

Then I have decided to add observable

```
this.attachments = ko.observableArray([]);
```

to my modelview and then tired to do

```
this.attachment.push(oAttachment);
```

where `oAttachment` is an object taken from `aFiles` array but still I'm getting the same error.

My question is how or even if can I update observable `attachments` from one modelview executing another modelview?

PS.
When I will do code below in the `ComposePopupView()` it works fine

```
var aFiles = [JSON.parse('{"isDir": false,  "name": "koala.jpg", "bytes": 780831,"link": "http://localhost/data/koala.jpg","id": "id:UxmT1S5QcFAAAAAAAAAACw"}')];

if (aFiles && aFiles[0] && aFiles[0]['link'])
{
  console.log("Test");
  self.addDropboxAttachment(aFiles[0]);
}
```

So in this case how can I pass data `aFiles` from the `UsersDocumentsPopupView()` to `ComposePopupView()` modelview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up to using Knockout's pub/sub functionality.

Basic example below:

```
var postbox = ko.observable();

function MyModalViewA()
{
    var _self = this;
    var test = new Array();
    _self.rows = ko.observableArray([]);

    postbox.subscribe(function(newValue) {         
          _self.rows.push(newValue);
          //test = test.concat(newValue);
          console.log("Rows " + JSON.stringify(test));
      }, null, "NewRowAvailable"
      );
};

function MyModalViewB()
{
    var _self = this;

    _self.search = function() {

        var newRow = JSON.parse('{ "label" : "abc" }');
        postbox.notifySubscribers(newRow, "NewRowAvailable");      
    };
};

var vma = new MyModalViewA();
ko.applyBindings(vma, $("#vma").get(0));

var vmb = new MyModalViewB();
ko.applyBindings(vmb, $("#vmb").get(0));
```

The first view model subscribes to a specific topic and the second view model notifies through the postbox on that topic. There is no direct dependency on each other.

Certainly the postbox would not need to be global and could be passed into the view model constructor functions or just created inside a self-executing function.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/708647/

Also, the postbox could just be a `ko.subscribable()` (which is included in the ko.observable functions).

Answer (score 1):

`attachments` is a property on an *instance* of `ComposePopupView`.

`addDropboxAttachment` is a method on the prototype of `ComposePopupView` that has to be called with the `this` context referring to an `instance` of `ComposePopupView` in order to work.

There are several ways to solve the issue. For example:

- Most likely: you haven't created an instance yet:

  ```
  DropBox = __webpack_require__(/*! View/Popup/Compose */ 31);
  const dropBox = new DropBox();
  dropBox.addDropboxAttachment(aFiles[0]);
  ```
- Likely: You've already created an instance but can't access it: Pass a reference to the instance you want to refer to along in your constructors.
- Are you only going to ever create *one* instance of `ComposePopupView`? Have a look at the "Singleton" pattern. E.g.:

  ```
  // "Private" to the module
  const MySingletonClass = function() { /* ... */ }
  MySingletonClass.prototype.someMethod = function () { };

  let singletonInstance = null;

  // Only expose a way to get the instance:
  export const getSingletonInstance = function() {
    if (!singletonInstance) singletonInstance = new MySingletonClass();
    return singletonInstance;
  }

  // In another module:
  import { getSingletonInstance } from "./MySingletonClass";

  const dropBox = getSingletonInstance();
  dropBox.someMethod(aFiles[0]);
  ```
- Planning on creating *several* instances that share the `attachments` data? Make it a static value.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried to get it updated using PubSub but I was't lucky and posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931481/knockoutjs-and-pubsub-to-update-observable-array-between-views I will take a look at your example when I clear my head first ;)

Comment: OK, I have tried to go for the singleton of `ComposePopupView` but somehow I was not able to get it to work correctly for Rainloop existing code. Then I took approach to share `attachments` data - was able to get working instance of `ComposePopupView` in my modal, `attachments` got updated with my data but then the view for `ComposePopupView` wasn't updated with new observable data (expected to display number of attachments based on that observable array). Also what do you have on mind by making `attachments` data static?

Comment: Well, it came up that my modal is trying to update my view for `UsersDocumentsPopupView()` rather than update view for `ComposePopupView()`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: There are many ways to pass references along between viewmodels. If you link to a runnable snippet I can probably help, but it's kind of hard to solve without more context.

Comment: Full app code is here: https://repository.rainloop.net/v2/webmail/1.9.1/rainloop-community-1.9.1.333-507d264e3fd61436a255a96be3d64a49.zip and KnockoutJS part is located in the static/js/app.js as `View/Popup/Compose` module.